# JqGrid mvc add and populate new row

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid

facing an issue with jqgrid can anybody tell me how to set blank row data in jqgrid ?
I have my custom popup for edit/add row edit is working fine now i want to add new row with the user values (from popup), row added but its always null, and my understanding for this issue is initially i don't have any record in db that's why at the time of grid creating there is no row. so another question is how can i bind a jqgrid if there is no data in db ?it always bind headers and showing how to add blank row to set it in edit mode?

Comment: I think you should check your server side code when you add a record. If there are no records in db, this does not mean that the problem is in jqgrid. If there is no record, the grid display only the header this is by default. Since you use your own form with posting to the server, I recommend you to check your code and do some debugging at server side, when you add a record.

Comment: What about showing the code in client and serverside in order us to check it also? May you publish it (or a extract of it) and we'll see something wrong